# Adding tags to multiple SQS queues through a single cli command or a script

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, aws-cli, amazon-sqs, aws-resource-group

I have multiple aws sqs queues and some have tags but some do not. Now I want to add tags to the ones which do not have them. We have the cli command: aws sqs tag-queue to add tags for a single queue. Is it possible to add multiple tags to multiple queues through a single cli command or would I have to write it through any script.

Answer (score 0):

The cli command [`aws sqs tag-queue`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/tag-queue.html) can only target a single queue. However, you could write a script that loops over all queues and calls `tag-queue` for each.

```
#!/bin/bash

for url in $(aws sqs list-queues --output text --query 'QueueUrls')
do
  aws sqs tag-queue --queue-url $url --tags YourKey=YourValue
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`resourcegroupstaggingapi tag-resources`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/resourcegroupstaggingapi/tag-resources.html#examples) command to tag (almost) any arbitrary resources you'd like, not just SQS queues!

For example,

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi tag-resources \
--resource-arn-list arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:123456789:foobarqueue arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:123456789:fizzbuzzqueue \
--tags Foo=Bar,Fizz=Buzz
```

Note that you can also [do this in the console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/tag-editor.html) if you find that easier if you click on Resource Groups > Tag Editor at the top of the console.

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me using the AWS CLI** :

```
queueurl=https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/<yourAWSaccountnumber>/L7Cn

aws sqs tag-queue --queue-url $queueurl --tags Key1=Value1,Key2=Value2
```

**I recommend creating tags when initially creating the SQS queue using the AWS CLI :**

```
queuename=trymeout

aws sqs create-queue --queue-name $queuename --tags Key1=Value1,Key2=Value2
```

**Then check your tags after creating the SQS queue using the AWS CLI :**

```
 aws sqs list-queue-tags --queue-url https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/<yourAWSaccountnumber>/trymeout
```

Make sure you have the newest AWS CLI installed.
*Older versions of the AWS CLI can contain bugs so....*

To get my AWS CLI version I run :   `aws --version` and today I get:

`aws-cli/2.7.14 Python/3.9.11 Darwin/21.5.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off`